# Regular expression which contains only plain text

Tags: regex

i am matching a string with a regular expression. The String only contains plain text. It does not contains any special character such as (:,$,#,@,^,&,*). I am putting below expression. but it does not working.

```
/^[A-Z][a-z][0-9]|[A-Z][0-9][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z][0-9]|[a-z][0-9][A-Z]|[0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z]|[a-z]{100}$/
```

My target is to identify those string which contains upper special character. Anyone please help me to get the right REGX.

Thanks
Basudev

Comment: what do you mean by upper special character.?Also provide an example string you tried so far

Comment: i want to use like below string: 
"Distributor Code registration in new Prefix(350-240) and v 1.2 need to deploy."
That means i don't want :,$,#,@,^,&,* this character in my input.

Comment: Your example is absolutely unclear.

Comment: Actually i want a valid input as a string where no special character will pe present. please help me to find the regular expression.

Comment: which language you use do this?

Comment: i am using it in a javascript...Now i am using below code to detect @ and # but not working.

^[@# ]+$

Answer (score 0):

Use this `[^:$#@^&*]`.It will help you to find plain text with out `:$#@^&*` all this special character.
*Explanation:*

- I just use `[^a-z]` Matches any characters except those in the range `a-z`.
- In your case `a-z` is `:$#@^&*` and the first special character `^` is for skipping `:$#@^&*` this.

you can test [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: i am testing below string but still it's taking as input although one special character (&) is exist in the string.
"SCB Core & Scheduler V1.2 Deployment"

Answer (score 0):

use java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.Pattern classes to identify upper case character in your string. I am putting an example below which will give you the number of string containing Upper case letters and their start and end point in the whole string. I hope this will help you.:

```
        String REGEX = "[A-Z]";
        String INPUT = "My Name is Parnik Kumar Gaurav";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);   // get a matcher object
      int count = 0;

      while(m.find()) {
         count++;
         System.out.println("Match number "+count);
         System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
         System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
      }
      System.out.println("Final: "+count);
```

Comment: if i write something like `hello1234` then ?

Comment: it should be ok... i only discard if a string contains the upper special character only. Other all strings should be valid.